# Creating histogram for 10 coins flipped simultaneously for 1000 times using R

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I am new to R and just working on a statistics class project.

I have to create a histogram for 10 simultaneous coin flips, 1000 times. 
Here is my code for generating the 1000 flips and counting number of heads based on the assignment.

```
# one coin toss
coin <- c('heads','tails')


tossResult = NULL
# variables to store the counts of number of heads in each toss
heads7 = 0
headsLessOrEquatTo7 = 0
headsLessThat7 = 0
heads7OrMore = 0
headsMoreThan7 = 0
heads3 = 0
heads4 = 0

for (i in 1:1000) {
    # resetting number of heads to 0 before each iteration
    numOfHeads = 0
    tossResult = sample (coin, size = 10, replace = TRUE)
    numOfHeads = sum (tossResult == 'heads')
    hist(numOfHeads)
    if (numOfHeads == 7) {
        heads7 = heads7 + 1
    } 
    if (numOfHeads <= 7) {
       headsLessOrEquatTo7 = headsLessOrEquatTo7 + 1
    } 
    if (numOfHeads < 7) {
        headsLessThat7 = headsLessThat7 + 1
    } 
    if (numOfHeads >= 7) {
        heads7OrMore = heads7OrMore + 1
    } 
    if (numOfHeads > 7) {
        headsMoreThan7 = headsMoreThan7 + 1
    }
}
print (paste0("Exactly 7 Heads:: ", heads7))
print (paste0("7 Heads or fewer:: ", headsLessOrEquatTo7))
print (paste0("Fewer than 7 Heads:: ", headsLessThat7))
print (paste0("7 Heads or more:: ", heads7OrMore))
print (paste0("More than 7 Heads:: ", headsMoreThan7))
```

I need to produce the histogram for the number of heads in each iteration. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To clarify: you're wanting to plot a histogram for each of the 1000 flips? Or are you wanting a histogram of the total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function that counts number of heads in one iteration.

```
count_heads <- function() {
    tossResult = sample(c('heads','tails'), 10, replace = TRUE)
    sum(tossResult == 'heads')
}
```

Use `replicate` to repeat it 1000 times and plot histogram

```
hist(replicate(1000, count_heads()), xlab = "number of heads", 
      main = "Histogram of number of heads")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Ronak, I will use this and could you also suggest me a good place to read about how to make multiple shared x-axis plots. As far as I have read, I think that inbuilt histogram does not support multiple plots. I have found something called ggplot. Is it correct? I am trying to plot the probability of getting 0 - 10 heads on shared x-axis o the graph above.

Comment: yes, `ggplot2` makes it very simple for plotting. You can also read about facets that might be helpful.